# Do I have to inform a graduate program that just admitted me about my attendance to a different program?

Tags: graduate-admissions, etiquette, communication

I have received acceptance from a graduate program physician assistant. I have already been attending this semester a different program. I want to withdraw and attend the other program. Do i have to inform the 2nd program that i have been attending the current program or its not needed since i have already been accepted 3 weeks ago.

Answer (score 1):

I can't see any need to notify the second program. It would be courteous, and may be necessary, to tell the current program, depending on circumstances. They may need to fill the slot you are leaving as is the case in many medical programs.